# Find $\min(\max(x+y,2x-y+2))$ under $x+2y\ge 4, x\ge 0, y\ge 0$

Tags: solution-verification, linear-programming

Find $\min(\max(x+y,2x-y+2))$ under $x+2y\ge 4, x\ge 0, y\ge 0$.

My attempt: In the region defined by the constraints, we have that $f(x,y)=\max(x+y,2x-y+2)=2x-y+2$. So, I believe that it is enough to minimize $2x-y+2$ under the given constraints. There is no solution, because there is no level set that shares a unique point or side with the defined region.

However [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min%28max%28x%2By%2C2x-y%2B2%29%29%20for%20x%2B2y%3E%3D%204%2C%20x%3E%3D0%2C%20y%3E%3D0) tells that there is a minimum, which is the point $(0,2)$. How can I come to this conclusion? This point is intersection of $2x-y+2=0$ with $x+2y=4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can minimize the maximum via linear programming by introducing an additional variable $z$ and minimizing $z$ subject to the original constraints and
\begin{align}
z &\ge x+y\\
z &\ge 2x-y+2\\
\end{align}

Comment: That's was a lot of work, but I managed to do it this way. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can get to the solution graphically. If you draw the restrictions and the contours of $f(x,y)= \max\{x+y,2x-y+2\}$, you'll easily realise that the minimum is actually attained at $(0,2)$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this question (and any similar question) into a standard problem as follows.

If $x+y\ge 2x-y+2$ then you must minimise $x+y$. So make $2y\ge x+2$ an extra constraint and find the  minimum of $x+y$ in a standard way.

Similarly, minimise $2x-y+2$ when $2y<x+2$.

Finally compare the two answers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved it for the first case and I did indeed find (0,2). Ideally, I would have to find the same value for the second case, right? But suppose that the latter gives another point, does that mean that there is no solution (unbounded? infeasible?)

Comment: You simply need the minimum of the values of the objective function found in each case.